# Is it possible to pass a const char pointer as a parameter for a constructor (initialization list) for a character pointer member variable?

Tags: c++, class, initializer-list

I'm trying to write an initialization list for my 2nd constructor but I don't know where to begin.

```
#ifndef ASTRING_H
#define ASTRING_H value

#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class AString {
private:
  char* data;
  int size;

public:

  // Default constructor
  AString () : data('\0'), size(0){};
  // Copy from cstring
  AString (const char*);  // <- this is the constructor I'm having issues
                         //     writing an initialization list for
};

#endif
```

Comment: 'I don't know where to begin' is not a problem description, and neither is 'this is the constructor I'm having trouble with', especially when it is buried in the code. The question in your title is readily answered by experiment. On your part.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that semantically a `const char*` is different from a `char*`. The first doesn't allow the pointed data to be changed, which is allowed for the latter.

Since the member variable is a `char*` by design, it's implicit that it's required to be modifiable. You can adjust your code to copy the passed data to the member variable or just forget about everything and use `std::string`:

```
class AString {
private:
  std::string data;

public:
  AString(const char* data) : data(data) { }
};
```

To copy the data you would need to get length through `strlen` and remember to `delete []` in destructor.